# get something done by somebody negative

Tags: past-tense

I have the following sentences,

1. She did not get her hand kissed by the gentlemen, since ... (correct imo)
2. She did not get her hand kiss by the gentlemen, since ... (incorrect imo)

Now, I want to know which one is the correct one, I think its the first one, but I don't know the formal grammar rule, as in many cases with languages which are not native to me, the first one just "feels" right. If its correct, could you tell me why after using "did not" (already indicating past tense) "kissed" should be used ? Does the effect of "did't" cancel out with the verb get (not got). Thanks.

Comment: Kissed is the past participle of the verb kiss, because it's being used as an adverb to modify get.

Comment: The "did" takes the past tense off the "get". She got X  → She did not get X. What she didn't get, what the X is, is completely beyond the point. It could be just one word, like "satisfaction", or several words, like "a nice present", or an entire phrase, like "her hand kissed by the distinguished gentlemen standing around like a bunch of oxen looking at the bluish-gray curtains and contemplating about what Nietzische could have possibly meant when he said 'I like turtles'". The *did* belongs to the *get* and to nothing else. Not to Nietzsche, not to curtains, not to the kiss.

Comment: But *kissed is correct* and kiss is not, in the given sentence. I suppose kissed is really the past participle acting as an adjective modifying "hand" there, rather than an adverb as I stated incorrectly before.